# How to extend model from another database?

Tags: django, django-models, ldap

I have two databases: 1. on LDAP server 2. on my computer( sqlite3 )

I'm trying to extend LDAP model without interference in this database.

Here are two models

1.

```
# LDAP_Profile_model


class LDAP_Profile(ldapdb.models.Model):

    base_dn = "dc=goldfarb,dc=corp"
    object_classes = ['user']

    username = CharField(db_column='sAMAccountName',unique=True)
    first_name = CharField(db_column='givenName')
    last_name = CharField(db_column='sn')
    full_name = CharField(db_column='cn')
    email = CharField(db_column='mail',unique=True,primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s (%s)" % (self.full_name,self.username)
```

2.

```
# Custom_Profile

class Custom_Profile(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(LDAP_Profile, primary_key=True)
    home_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = USStateField()
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Its a bit unclear. So you want to extend `LDAP_Profile`  in `Custom_Profile` model?

Comment: Yes, exactly and I don't want to interfere with the LDAP database.
I edited Custom_Profile (added OnetoOneField)

Comment: Ok, then did you get any error while running `syncdb` or 'makemigrations'? If not, are you sure `LDAP_Profile` is properly imported/reachable?

Comment: No erros. Btw I don't know how to populate Custom_Profile for example username = 'Bob' in django shell.

Comment: Then I think You are good to go. Sorry You said `how to populate Custom_Profile in django shell` . It is same as you are doing in code. 
Like `import Custom_Profile`  Then, `Custom_Profile.objects.all()`

Comment: If I type that in shell I got empty list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80398/discussion-between-herehere-and-swagat).

Comment: Yeah, because it is empty. create a object first. I hope, you know how to create an object. Still you need help, ask me.